# In and out, and back in again

Tags: chess, optimization

With White to move, how long will it take for both sides to cooperate, i.e. this is a [helpmate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helpmate), and checkmate Black?

[image]

This is based on a problem made made by Otto Blathy. And yes, I know that the postion is illegal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently on mobile, so I'll have to provide the full list of moves later, but I think I have it ending with:

> 60 Qg4++

The full list of moves:

> 1. Kxg1 Kg5
>  2. Kh1 Kg6
>  3. Kg1 Kg7
>  4. Kh1 Kf8
>  5. Kg1 Ke8
>  6. Kh1 Kd8
>  7. Kg1 Kc8
>  8. Kh1 Kb8
>  9. Kg1 Ka7
>  10. Kh1 Ka6
>  11. Kg1 Ka5
>  12. Kh1 Ka4
>  13. Kg1 Ka3
>  14. Kh1 Kb2
>  15. Kg1 Kc1
>  16. Kh1 Kd1
>  17. Kg1 Kxe1
>  18. Kh1 Kd1
>  19. Kg1 Kc1
>  20. Kf1 Kb2
>  21. Ke1 Ka3
>  22. Kd1 Ka4
>  23. Kc1 Ka5
>  24. Kb1 Ka6
>  25. Ka2 Ka7
>  26. Ka3 Kb8
>  27. Ka4 Kc8
>  28. Ka5 Kd8
>  29. Ka6 Ke8
>  30. Kb7 Kf8
>  31. Kc8 Kg7
>  32. Kd8 Kh6
>  33. Ke8 Kh7
>  34. Kf7 Kh8
>  35. Kg6 Kg8
>  36. Kh6 Kf8
>  37. Kh7 Ke8
>  38. Kg8 Kd8
>  39. Kf8 Kc8
>  40. Ke8 Kb8
>  41. Kd8 Ka7
>  42. Kc8 Ka6
>  43. Kb8 Ka5
>  44. Ka7 Ka4
>  45. Ka6 Ka3
>  46. Ka5 Kb2
>  47. Ka4 Kc1
>  48. Ka3 Kd1
>  49. Ka2 Ke1
>  50. Ka1 Kf1
>  51. Ka2 Kxg2
>  52. Ka3 Kh3
>  53. Ka4 g2
>  54. Ka5 g1=Q
>  55. Ka6 Qg7
>  56. Ka7 Qf7
>  57. exf7 Kh4
>  58. f8=Q Kh3
>  59. Qg8 Kh4
>  60. Qg4#